# Is there a name or symbol for the matrix division resulting in a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology

I am not talking about the inverse matrix, $A^{-1}$ which gives $A\times A^{-1}=I$, but rather the operation $\frac{1}{n}tr(\space\cdot \times A^{-1})$, which gives 1 when applied to a $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Comment: Right. Corrected the question.

Comment: Where did you come up with this operation? Did you make it, or find it somewhere?

Comment: In "Group Theory and Physics" (Sternberg), he mentions a bijective function between the (real) four-vectors and the vector space of 2x2 self-adjoint matrices. Each four vector (x0,x1,x2,x3,x4) is associated with a 2x2 self adjoint matrix by multiplying the components of that four vector with each one of the four Pauli matrice, respectively (they make up a basis for the vector space of 2x2 self adjoint matrices). If I want to to write out the inverse function going from the 2x2 self adjoint matrices to the four-vectors, I have to use the operator I mention above to obtain the components.